# Use jQuery to check if text equals an html special character

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html special character I want to toggle off and on like a check box.  In this instance, it's a star: ☆ that can become filled in: ★.

I want to check the state of the star when it is clicked.

```
$(".action_table_star").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "&#9733;") {
        $(this).html("&#9734;");
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    } else {
        $(this).html("&#9733;");
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255,165,0)');
    }
});
```

This doesn't work though because $(this).html() is never equal to "&#9733".  How can I rewrite this if statement to I guess decode the html special character and check it's "state"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving on SpYk3HH's suggestion, I would approach this by adding both stars to the document, one with `display:none`, and use jQuery to toggle them both on click.

An additional benefit is that you can now style each star individually with CSS instead of jQuery, which is as it should be.

HTML:

```
<div class="action_star">
  <span class="star1">&#9733;</span>
  <span style="display:none" class="star2">&#9734;</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.action_star').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.star1,.star2').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfjT5/1/

Less code, more clear, more readable, much better.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.html()`, use `.text()` in conjunction with a `\uxxxx` sequence, or [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

```
$(".action_table_star").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == String.fromCharCode(9733)) {
        $(this).html("&#9734;");
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    } else {
        $(this).html("&#9733;");
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255,165,0)');
    }
});
```

When the `\uxxxx` method is used, you have to convert the base-10 numeric charcode to a base-16 one. Example (in console):

```
(9734).toString(16);
// Returns 2606. Now, paste `"\u2606"` in your code
```

Don't forget to padd sufficient zeros to get 4 digits.

Comment: This was such a beautiful explanation. I'd give more than 1 upvote if I could.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be not to depend on a character but a class added and removed instead, like so:

```
$(".action_table_star").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("star-checked")) {
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255,165,0)').text("☆");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('color', '#fff').text("★");
    };
    $(this).toggleClass("star-checked");
})
```

[***See Demo jsFiddle HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/MMaDJ/)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
escape($(this).html()) == "%u2605"
```

where `%u2605` is the the filled star symbol escaped.

Answer (score 0):

No, `$(this).html()` will never equal `&#9733;`, but it *will* equal ★

http://jsfiddle.net/hJdg4/1/

```
$(".action_table_star").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "★") {
        $(this).html("&#9734;");
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    } else {
        $(this).html("&#9733;");
        $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255,165,0)');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $(this).text()=='★'